# How to copy text within parentheses to the start of the line?

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

I would like to know the expression to perform this action for a 1000+ lines.

**Before:**

```
Insurgent (2015)
The Lazarus Effect (2015)
Cinderella (2015)
Platoon Leader (1988)
The Gunman (2015)
Woman in Gold (2015)
```

**After:**

```
2015 - Insurgent
2015 - The Lazarus Effect
2015 - Cinderella
1988 - Platoon Leader
2015 - The Gunman
2015 - Woman in Gold
```

I know how to

- Find (everything in a parenthesis) `\([^()]+\)`

But I don't know the expression to

- Copy/Move characters to the start/beginning of a line.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the find/replace dialog, make sure you check the box for regular expressions. Then search for:

```
^(.+?)\s+\((\d+)\)$
```

And replace with:

```
$2 - $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to do this.

Open the replace box (CTRL+h), Check the `Regular Expression` radio in the bottom of the replace box.

Then on the `Find what` field put: `(.+)\((\d+)\)`

On the `Replace with` field put: `$2 - $1`

Then hit on Replace All button